# How to do gear physics

Tags: unity, physics

I've realized this gear using primitive. 
[image]

My object is:

- Main cylinder with 
  with a Rigidbody and a script who rotate Y axis

  - All Prism as child who has MeshCollider

[image]

I've got also a pivot for each gear.

The problem is that the right gear not rotate when "prism" collide with others. 
The collision not happen.

Any ideas ?

Thanks

Comment: How are you causing the gear to rotate?

Comment: transform.Rotate (new Vector3 (x, y, z) * SpeedRotation);

Comment: The problem is that not cause moving the second gear

Comment: That'll do it. Transform.Rotate doesn't impart a physics force. Can you try rotating the gear with a Rigidbody torque or angular velocity and see if that changes anything?

Comment: Are the teeth passing through eachother? What exactly do you mean by “the collision is not happening”?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you have a rigidbody on a game object, you generally should refrain from manipulating its `transform` directly. Doing so confuses the physics engine, because you are literally teleporting the object around.

If you want to manipulate the object, use the methods of `rigidbody` instead. If you want the object to turn, use [`rigidbody.AddTorque`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.AddTorque.html).

By the way: If gear physics are a central game mechanic of your game (like in a mechanical puzzle game) you might want to implement them yourself instead of relying on the Unity physics engine. Having so many small physics object in the scene with interactions which matter for the gameplay is going to end in a disaster.